# Best estimate of biased coin

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-probability

I came across this question that had a solution, and I wanted to discuss how they got their solution, and whether it is better than a MLE solution and why that might be.

There is a loaded coin that flips tails with probability $p$, where $p$ is known only to be distributed uniformly on the interval $[0,1]$. The coin is flipped five times, each time turning up tails. What is the best estimate of $p$?

There is an MLE solution to this that says it is $\frac{5}{5} = 1$. However, is this solution considering that $p$ "is known only to be distributed uniformly on the interval $[0,1]$?

The solution provided takes a Bayesian approach. To be honest, I don't understand it, and if anyone could explain that would be really helpful.
$$
\begin{split}
E[p | T^5] & = \int_0^1 P(p|T^5]p \text{d}p \\
& = \int_0^1 \frac{P(p|T^5)P(p) \text{d}p}{\int_0^1 P(p|T^5)P(p) \text{d}p} p \text{d}p = \frac{\int_0^1 p^6\text{d}p}{\int_0^1 p^5\text{d}p} = \frac{6}{7}
\end{split}
$$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This question doesn't make sense without specifying in more detail what is meant by "best estimate." The MLE estimate is a standard choice, and is equivalent to giving the value of $p$ whose a posteriori probability is maximized given a uniform prior. The given solution computes the posterior mean which is just a different number which is used for different purposes.

Comment: If you simulated a lot of cases with $p$ taken from a uniform distribution, and then flipped a biased coin $5$ times and kept those $p$ which produced $5$ tails and then took the average of the $p$ you kept, then you would get $\frac67$ (with some simulation noise).

Comment: The Bayesian approach is to say that the posterior density is proportional to the product of the prior density (here $1$ as it is uniform) and the likelihood (here a binomial $p^5$).  So here $p^5$ times the  constant which makes the posterior density  integrate to $1$, which is $\frac1{\int_0^1 p^5\text{d}p}=6$ and thus a density $6p^5$ on $[0,1]$.  If you have a quadratic loss function for errors then the optimal point estimate is the expectation of the posterior density, here $\int_0^1 p \cdot 6 p^5\text{d}p=\frac67$.

Comment: One simple approach, which relies on knowing what [conjugate priors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) are, uses the [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with two parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$. We use the Beta distribution because it is the conjugate prior for the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). It turns out that $B(0, 0)$ is the same thing as a uniform distribution, and if you take $B(\alpha, \beta)$ as a prior and then observe $m$ heads and $n$ tails, the posterior is $B(\alpha+m, \beta+n)$.

Comment: (You may not be conversant with those terms; that's OK, they may be of use to someone.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement "$p$ has a uniform distribution" is called the "prior" distribution of $p$. It carries information and so to ignore it will usually lead to a less efficient estimator (unless the prior is wrong, then the estimator could be badly biased).

The MLE is totally fine if we don't have a prior (or don't believe it).

In Bayesian  statistics we are essentially assuming that the model we are trying to perform inference on was drawn from some larger distribution of possible models. In practice what this means is that the "fixed parameters" are pushed up one level to hyperparameters.

In this case, $p$ follows prior distribution $f_0(p) = \text{Uniform}(0,1)(p)$ so the hyperparameters are $0$ and $1$ for the endpoints of the interval. In classic Bayesian inference we don't try to infer these (or we do that before the experiment). There is a branch called [Empirical Bayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_Bayes_method) where you do infer the hyperparameters from the data. But let's keep it simple for this problem.

The full probability model for observing $x$ Heads and $y$ tails then becomes:
$$P(x,y)=\int_0^1f_0(p)P(x,y|p)dp$$

Once we observe our value $x=0,y=5$ in your case, we can get the conditional distribution of $p$ which will adjust the probability distribution of $p$ to be consistent with the observed data.

$$f(p|H^xT^y)=\frac{f(p,x,y)}{P(x,y)}=\frac{f_0(p)P(x,y|p)}{\int_0^1f_0(p)P(x,y|p)dp}$$

$f(p|H^xT^y)$ is called the *posterior distribution of p* and reflects the "updated prior" based on our observations. It is the distribution of $p$ that is consistent with the data (so some $p$ values are rendered less likely and others more)

Comment: OK... so what's the answer?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork — what do you mean? I’m explaining the Bayesian approach that the OP was confused about.

Comment: So you agree the answer is $\frac{6}{7}$?

Comment: @Annika thank! And when we look for the expected value of this distribution we just have $E[f(p |H^xT^y)]=\int_0^1f(p |H^xT^y)p\text{d}p$, right?

Comment: @nezamjazayeri -- correct. You can shortcut this by recognizing that the posterior distribution is a $\text{Beta}(\alpha=6,\beta=1)$ which has expected value $\frac67$ :)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I don't think the OP is asking if I agree with the answer. However, given that the MLE is on the boundary of the parameter space, and our sample is small, then yes, I'm inclined to believe the Bayesian estimate of $\frac67$ more than $1$.